# D3 Floorplan custom colour the heatmaps

Tags: d3.js, colorbrewer

I would like to colour the heatmaps in the D3 Floorplan library with custom hexidecimal values. For example "heatmap1 = '#000'".

https://github.com/dciarletta/d3-floorplan

It states it uses http://colorbrewer2.org/ for it's colour functionality.

I would like the colour of the heatmaps to change according to a sliding timeline, which can be slid by the user. In other words if it's Jan 2016, the heatmap is green and if it's Feb 2016 the heatmap is red.

Does anyone have an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the way to edit colours explicitly is doing what Mark said by modifying the CSS and then:

```
heatmap.colorMode(['custom']);
heatmap.customThresholds([1, 2, 3]); // choose the values you want to indicate a change of colour
```

Then update the map:

```
mapdata[heatmap.id()] = data.heatmap;
d3.select("#demo")
    .datum(mapdata)
    .call(map);
```

You then modify the value in the JSON heatmaps element and this correlates to the class names i.e. ".d6-6".

Answer (score 3):

The colors are defined in `d3.floorplan.css` as

```
.RdYlBu .d6-6 {fill:#D73027;background:#D73027;color:#121212}
.RdYlBu .d6-5 {fill:#FC8D59;background:#FC8D59;color:#121212}
.RdYlBu .d6-4 {fill:#FEE090;background:#FEE090;color:#121212}
.RdYlBu .d6-3 {fill:#E0F3F8;background:#E0F3F8;color:#121212}
.RdYlBu .d6-2 {fill:#91BFDB;background:#91BFDB;color:#121212}
.RdYlBu .d6-1 {fill:#4575B4;background:#4575B4;color:#121212}
```

You can simply redefine this definitions in your own `css` and load it **after** `d3.floorplan.css`

---

Running example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Floor Plan - local coordinate map layers for D3.js</title>
  <script data-require="d3@2.10.0" data-semver="2.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dciarletta.github.io/d3-floorplan/d3.floorplan.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('http://dciarletta.github.io/d3-floorplan/d3.floorplan.css');
    body {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 50px auto 20px;
      width: 720px;
      background: #fcfcfc;
      line-height: 1.45em;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #555;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: #000;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0 20px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    div.code {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: #eee;
      margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 720px;
    }
    
    .RdYlBu .d6-6 {fill:red;background:#D73027;color:#121212}
    .RdYlBu .d6-5 {fill:green;background:#FC8D59;color:#121212}
    .RdYlBu .d6-4 {fill:purple;background:#FEE090;color:#121212}
    .RdYlBu .d6-3 {fill:black;background:#E0F3F8;color:#121212}
    .RdYlBu .d6-2 {fill:orange;background:#91BFDB;color:#121212}
    .RdYlBu .d6-1 {fill:blue;background:#4575B4;color:#121212}
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo"></div>

  <script id="demo-code" type="text/javascript">
    var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 50.0])
      .range([0, 720]),
      yscale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 33.79])
      .range([0, 487]),
      map = d3.floorplan().xScale(xscale).yScale(yscale),
      imagelayer = d3.floorplan.imagelayer(),
      heatmap = d3.floorplan.heatmap(),
      vectorfield = d3.floorplan.vectorfield(),
      pathplot = d3.floorplan.pathplot(),
      overlays = d3.floorplan.overlays().editMode(true),
      mapdata = {};

    mapdata[imagelayer.id()] = [{
      url: 'http://dciarletta.github.io/d3-floorplan/Sample_Floorplan.jpg',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      height: 33.79,
      width: 50.0
    }];

    map.addLayer(imagelayer)
      .addLayer(heatmap)
      .addLayer(vectorfield)
      .addLayer(pathplot)
      .addLayer(overlays);

    d3.json("http://dciarletta.github.io/d3-floorplan/demo-data.json", function(data) {
      mapdata[heatmap.id()] = data.heatmap;
      mapdata[overlays.id()] = data.overlays;
      mapdata[vectorfield.id()] = data.vectorfield;
      mapdata[pathplot.id()] = data.pathplot;

      d3.select("#demo").append("svg")
        .attr("height", 487).attr("width", 720)
        .datum(mapdata).call(map);
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I'm wanting to achieve is set colours specifically to heatmaps then change that colour based on a scrolling timeline to indicate state of that room. I'm still having trouble grasping the concept of this as it seems to set colours according to the number of heatmaps. I'll keep investigating but any tips would be most welcome?